# How to find strings that don't contain within itself a certain substring

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For example I have the text:

```
goodstring sometext other text perfectstring 
goodstring badstring perfectstring 
goodstring 14554 sometext perfectstring
```

I need a regular expression that finds all lines except those that contain **badstring** between "goodstring" and "perfectstring".
So I need something like this:

```
goodstring\s(^badstring)\sperfectstring
```

What is right to replace the **^badstring**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern:

```
goodstring\s(?:(?!badstring).)*\sperfectstring
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP4pM3/1)

- `(?!badstring)` is negative lookahead assertion meaning we don't have `badstring` at next position
- `(?:(?!badstring).)*` will match 0 more character that don't have `badstring` at next position.